# CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED error in PyTorch Linear layer

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm getting the following CUDA error when training a model in PyTorch with a NVIDIA RTX A5000:

> /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1670525552843/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:92: operator(): block: [0,0,0], thread: [43,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.

> RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasLtMatmul( ltHandle, computeDesc.descriptor(), &alpha_val, mat1_ptr, Adesc.descriptor(), mat2_ptr, Bdesc.descriptor(), &beta_val, result_ptr, Cdesc.descriptor(), result_ptr, Cdesc.descriptor(), &heuristicResult.algo, workspace.data_ptr(), workspaceSize, at::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream())`

This is happening in the middle of my model at the input to a nn.Linear layer, between 1-7 batches into the start of training in the first epoch. I've double checked and the input matrix's final dimension matches the layer's in_features ([64,120,128] and 128, where the weight shape is [32,128]). What are some reasons this could be happening? This has not happened with similar models I've trained in the past, and is **not happening** with my laptop's NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU.

I've looked into potential memory issues. When printing out the memory usage directly before this operation with psutil.virtual_memory and pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo, it looks like 16.27GB and 16.74GB of memory are still available on CPU RAM and on the GPU right before the job fails.

More details: I'm using PyTorch 1.13.1 on both my laptop and the remote cluster nodes that have the RTX A5000 (the model is failing on different nodes with separate RTX A5000s). I'm using CUDA 1.22 on the laptop and 1.16 remotely. The model uses modules from fairseq (version 0.12.2 on both computers).